# how does TypeORM handle multiple connection.manager.save() when fails

Tags: database, typeorm

The following example is from the [Doc](https://orkhan.gitbook.io/typeorm/docs/many-to-one-one-to-many-relations):

```
const photo1 = new Photo();
photo1.url = "me.jpg";
await connection.manager.save(photo1);

const photo2 = new Photo();
photo2.url = "me-and-bears.jpg";
await connection.manager.save(photo2);

const user = new User();
user.name = "John";
user.photos = [photo1, photo2];
await connection.manager.save(user);
```

My question is what happen if one of the query fails. Will it cause the previous query save into the database.

I was always doing the following to make sure the transaction wouldn't corrupt the database in case something fails.

```
await getConnection().transaction( async transactionalEntityManager => {
 //anything inside
}
```

I wonder if both are equivalent since official doc uses it everywhere. For relation like `manytomany` and `onetomany`, it's quite important to keep the data consistency. I'm slightly worried but did not find answer from my web search

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, you have to be concerned about running multiple queries in transaction.

Fortunately Typeorm is implemented that way, that these methods use transactions internally. When you execute these commands, every query sent to the database are in transaction, so in this case, we'll have 3 separate transactions:

- two for saving the photo records separately
- one for saving the user and updateing the photos.

You must know, that, altough typeorm handles the queries well by encapsulating all of them in transaction, it does not encapsulate the whole process. If it's important to always save these users with their photos, (maybe because this is your user-story) you must wrap the whole process in transaction. In this case, your final solution must be:

```js
await connection.transaction(async (transactionalEntityManager) => {
    const photo1 = new Photo();
    photo1.url = "me.jpg";
    await connection.manager.save(photo1);

    const photo2 = new Photo();
    photo2.url = "me-and-bears.jpg";
    await connection.manager.save(photo2);

    const user = new User();
    user.name = "John";
    user.photos = [photo1, photo2];
    await connection.manager.save(user);
  });
```

I hope it helps for you!

Comment: Thx. That's the main thing I concern about. For simple web application, transactions are usually bind to Api request, there are a lot of uncertainties behinds the mutation. So when failure happens, I want to fail all and fail hard. Otherwise, dealing with data corruption seems like a bigger pain for me, since user will always retry if something wrong.